# Vertical text selection in python (spyder)

Tags: python, spyder

As python requires indentation, i'd like have a fast way to remove/add indentation to many lines at the same time. For example: in Rstudio i'd do alt+mouse select and get this:[image]

Is there a way to do the same on python, so i could remove, for example, the space on [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhFXR.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a block of code and press TAB to indent or shift + TAB to unindent in Spyder.

Comment: Shift+tab has worked for altering the indentation so thanks! But the example i gave with Rstudio does more than that, i can edit the text in two lines at the same time there for example (i.stack.imgur.com/eJ5X6.png).

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro I don't use spyder, so I'm not really sure how to do it, but this page seems it has some info about multiple cursors: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2112